# How to use sed command to add the contents of a command output at a particular position in a file?

Tags: shell, unix, sed

I have following file.

```
cat addtext
This is sparta. 
Bye.

cat mainfile
abc
pqr
```

I want my output to look like -

```
This is sparta. 
abc
pqr
Bye.
```

i.e. the contents of first file added from the 2nd line of another file. 
I am trying this using sed command.

```
sed -i '1s/^/$filecontent\n/' abc.test
```

where

```
filecontent=`cat addtext`
```

But it is not replacing the value of variable and appending the value $filecontent instead of what it contents i.e contents of addtext file. 
How do I resolve this? How do we use other commands inside sed?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need sed just use `cat`:

```
cat file2 fil1
```

Equivalent sed command:

```
sed '' file2 file1
```

Or to insert content of file2 in file1 after line 1 use:

```
sed '1 r file2' file1
```

Comment: I am just trying to understand how can we use other commands in sed.
I also want to add the file content at any position in the main file, not just the beginning. How do I do that?

Comment: "sed" is not the tool to concatenate two files into a single stream of data.  "cat" is that command.  "sed" is an editor.  A Stream EDitor.  Pick the right tool for the job, and if you're trying to learn a new tool, pick a task for it that's appropriate for the tool.

Comment: @ghoti Okay. How do I add the file content at line number n using cat?

Comment: @AjimBagwan: I have provided you a sed command doing that. `sed '1 r file2' file1` inserts file at line # 2

Comment: sed '' file2 file1 is working to show the output on the prompt. But sed -i '' file2 file1 is somehow not working to make changes to the file in question.

Comment: You can't use `sed -i '' file2 file1` but can use `sed -i '1 r file2' file1`

Comment: @AjimBagwan, adding at line 2 wasn't what your question originally asked.  anubhava's answer is the correct one.  (The other one is also correct, but it's basically the same answer.)

Comment: @ghoti: Yes that's right, OP was asking a bonus question :)

Answer (score 1):

```
LineWhere=1
File2Insert=addtext
File2Modify=mainfile

sed "${LineWhere} r ${File2Insert}" ${File2Modify} > DestinationFile
```

Action is to `r` read a file when at line specified. Variable are just here to show how to and be generic (double quote mandatory in this case)